# App not receiving broadcast when originated in Launcher but receiving when originated from other App

Tags: android, manifest, broadcast

I Have an app that is showing a toast when receiving broadcast and action equals BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED, everything is working OK, but the problem here is that I want to do something when bluetooth is turning on but when bluetooth is activated from a button of the launcher it seems like the broadcast is arriving late or my app is receiving late or something like that, because when I started Bluetooth from other app, the receiver works great and on time.

Any suggestion in what is the problem? I have the receiver registered in manifest.

and it seems that sometimes loops infinitely because I have two toast to show when bluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED and it shows infinitely

Any idea of why is happening this and previous things?

Receiver:

```
public class Receivers extends BroadcastReceiver {

protected static AlertObject BTTurningOn = new AlertObject();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String action = intent.getAction();


    this.context=context;


    if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                                             BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);




        if(state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON && BTTurningOn.Activated == true)
        {
            Alert(BTTurningOn);
        }






    }


}
```

BTTurningOn is just an object with some boolean variables to know whether to attend the broadcast message or not

Here is the important part of manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receivers">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When I start the bluetooth from my other app or from Adjusts/ wireless connections it works great, but its not working when I start it from an icon of the launcher or the upper bar where notifications appear, Im using GO Launcher EX Version 2.76

My other app get the broadcast and works great from the site that this app is not getting, but the difference is only where I register the receiver, this app is in MAnifest and other app is on one Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: **I did not have the bluetooth permission** in manifest, but it's kinda strange because it did not receive broadcast messages when originated from Launcher but actually the app received them when originated from my other app